# Parse a text to a data model

Tags: algorithm, parsing, machine-learning, text-mining

I'm trying to parse a text into a data model i created, specifically monsters from and RPG book. I extract the text from pdf, it looks like this:

```
Dire Rat
From age to age, dire rats vary in size. In this age, they're only half
as big as they sometimes get, but they're also twice as vicious.
1
st
 level mook [beast ]
Initiative: +2
Infected bite +5 vs. AC-4 ongoing damage
AC 15
PD 15  HP 6 (mook)
MD 10
Mook: Kill one dire rat mook for every 6 damage you deal to the mob.
```

And here's my desired data model, happened to write it in C#:

```
public interface IMonsterData
    {
        string Name { get; }
        int Level { get; set; }
        string Role { get; set; }
        string Type { get; set; }
        int Initiative { get; set; }
        int ArmorClass { get; set; }
        int PhysicalDefense { get; set; }
        int MentalDefense { get; set; }
        int HealthPoints { get; set; }
    }
```

The desired result would look like this:

```
Name = Dire Rat
Level = 1
Role = mook
Type = beast
Initiative = 2
ArmourClass = 15
PhysicalDefense = 15
MentalDefense = 10
HealthPoints = 6
```

The source text has these monsters spread out in a section of a book, so the majority of pages have no monsters, then comes a section whith monsters. Some fit on a page, some are split, but i don't think that matters since i've parsed out all text out of the book as a string using a tool i found.

I've approached this problem with manual parsing using C# and .Net, byt finding rows that only have "st, nd, rd, th" and finding the AC, PD in between such rows, but i have a feeling that this is a good case to solve with Text Mining or some other form of Machine Learning.

Problem is i don't know anything about machine learning or the correct algorithm from text mining to use on this, and i can only get so far googling around without knowing any keywords.

What sort of library, algorithm or similar should i use to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a case to be solved by good-old regex.
I'd approach this as follows:

- Filter out the useless records(the ones that dont contain the relevant fields) from whatever you've been able to scrape so far.
- flatten each of those relevant records into a line so that it is easy
  to parse with a regex query.
- Try a regex query builder such as
  [this](https://regex101.com/) to extract the fields and place them into your model.

Comment: Agree - no machine learning needed if you can parse it with simple rules.